# Why function List data is not received out

Tags: list, flutter, dart, parameters, pass-by-reference

This is my code

```
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, non_constant_identifier_names, prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables, constant_identifier_names, prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables, unnecessary_string_interpolations, prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/Components/main_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/Components/setting_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/Components/stock_list.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class InterestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  InterestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InterestScreen> createState() => _InterestScreenState();
}

class _InterestScreenState extends State<InterestScreen> {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<void> _getstockList( List<Map<String,dynamic>> stockcardlist) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> docdata;
    Map<String, dynamic> stockdata;

    await firestore
        .collection('users')
    // user의 device token
        .doc('NVPjZEAZneKblrubGZSW')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      docdata = ds.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<dynamic> list = docdata['favorite'];
      for(var element in list){
        firestore
            .collection('stock')
            .where("name", isEqualTo: "${element}")
            .get()
            .then((QuerySnapshot qs) {
          stockdata = qs.docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          stockcardlist.add(stockdata);

        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> stockcardlist = [];
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getstockList(stockcardlist),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: mainAppBar(
                context,
                "관심 종목",
                SettingButton(context),
              ),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Cardlist(size, stockcardlist),
                ],
              ),
            );
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    },
    );
  }
}
```

**CardList Widget**

```
Widget Cardlist(Size size, List<Map<String, dynamic>> stockcardlist ) {
        print(stockcardlist.length();

        return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.05),
              itemCount: stockcardlist.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Stockcard(context, size, stockcardlist[index]['name'], stockcardlist[index]['price'],
                    stockcardlist[index]['perc'], stockcardlist[index]['volume']);
              },
            ),
        );
}
```

**Problem**

1. I get data from the fire store ( And it is successfull.
   snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done complete)
2. store it in the parameter stockcardlist using add
3. However, the stockcardlist list was delivered to the Cardlist Widget, but the value of

`print(stockcardlist.length();` is always zero. Similarly, the listview below is not executed

I thought the cause was execution before the data was delivered from the Firestore, but the if statement was executed normally and the list was delivered normally even if the list was built with the code that I did before.

please help me

Comment: Your `for` loop has `.then((QuerySnapshot qs) ...`, but the returned `Future` is never `await`ed, so `_getStocklist` will return before those `Future`s complete.  I *strongly* recommend enabling the [`unawaited_futures`](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#unawaited_futures) lint.  Additionally, you should avoid using `Future.then` and just use `await`, which also would have avoided this problem.

Comment: @jamesdlin really thank you about the answer but i dont understand why you recommend unawaited_furtures. i find that means 'used to  intentionally not awaited.' . but my problem is made by unwait and nothing returns to list. isn't it?

Comment: Your problem is that you created a `Future` that you forgot to `await`. `unawaited_future`s will warn you about any `Future`s that are not explicitly `await`ed and that are not explicitly ignored with `unawaited`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Could you please see my new quetion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044145/flutter-why-doesnt-async-and-await-work