# flutter Why doesn't async and await work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

**_getstockList**

```
    _getstockList( List<dynamic> nlist) async {
      Map<String, dynamic> userdocdata;

      var userdata = await  firestore.collection('users').doc('NVPjZEAZneKblrubGZSW').get();
      userdocdata = userdata.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      nlist = userdocdata['favorite'];
  }
```

**Main Code**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> list = [];
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> stockcardlist = [];
    _getstockList(list);
    print(list);                                           // output
    _getstockInfo(list, stockcardlist);
    

     ~~~
}
```

**_getstockInfo**

```
    _getstockInfo(List<dynamic> nlist, List<Map<String,dynamic>> stockcardlist){

      print(nlist.length);                                // output
    }
```

**Desired result**

`print(list)`

`print(nlist.length)`
valid value

BUT

**result**
`print(list)`  = []

`print(nlist.length)`  = 0

please help me i use Future, sync, unawait but i cant solve

Comment: You've made your code *worse* than in [your earlier version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72042010/). You removed the return type from `_getStockList` and now its caller is no longer using a `FutureBuilder` to wait for the returned `Future`. (Why?) Ultimately your problem is the same as before: you're not waiting for your asynchronous operations to complete.  Fix your return types, enable the `unawaited_futures` lint, and add `await` for the `Future`s that it reports.

Comment: @jamesdlin omg i understand perfectly, Thanks you very very  much

Comment: try then() for your async and print your list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `_getStockList` doesn't return anything. When you pass it, the original object remains unaffected. You could try to fix that:

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> _getstockList() async {
      Map<String, dynamic> userdocdata;

      var userdata = await firestore.collection('users').doc('NVPjZEAZneKblrubGZSW').get();
      userdocdata = userdata.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<dynamic> nlist = userdocdata['favorite'];
      return nlist;
  }
```

Now you need to call this function to fill the list

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> stockcardlist = [];
    List<dynamic> list = await _getstockList(); // DOES NOT WORK!
    print(list);                          
    _getstockInfo(list, stockcardlist);
    
     ...
}
```

However, this does not work, since you are not allowed to use `await` in `build`, which is not async. To get around this, you can use a `FutureBuilder`:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
    future: _getstockList(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
      List<dynamic> list = snapshot.data ?? [];

      print(list);
      
      return MyAwesomeScreenWithAList(list);
    }    
  );
}
```

Now if you want to use the results of the first async function in a second one, the easiest will probably be, though not ideal, to use two nested `FutureBuilder`s.

Comment: Thankyou i solve problem because of you. sorry but i cant click vote i haven't enough reputation but i am really appreciate you

Comment: You should be able to mark my answer as the 'solution' by clicking the check mark, if you want to